# cannot remove `/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` permission denied

Tags: installation, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface, kali-linux

I wanted to install GIT on my Kali-linux

for that I done this
[`apt install git`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzbbR.jpg)

But it showed an error,

so I tried this...

[`rm /var/lib/dpkag/lock-frontend` then `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5WsK.jpg)

It shows that file is removed but still the command is not running...

[I retried downloading git but still it shows an error `apt install git`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9tEP.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try running with `sudo` command. 
Command to run:

```
sudo apt install git-all
```

Ref: git official [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git).

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo apt install git. But since u have deleted tht file i fear it may cause problems